# Inconsistent Styling Behavior with Custom Inline Format in Quill.js

Tags: javascript, quill

I'm trying to create a text editor using Quill.js where every piece of text is embedded inside a custom inline format that I've defined. Additionally, I want to style the span elements with specific colors and background colors.

However, I'm encountering an issue where the styling is inconsistently applied. Every time I create a new line, an extra span is added that has my custom span as a child or the style gets applied correctly.
I have seen, when console logging the format, that sometimes it looks like this:  {background: 'yellow', custom: {…}}
or like this: {custom: {…}, background: 'yellow'}

this is my custom inline

```js
var Inline = Quill.import("blots/inline");

      class Custom extends Inline {
        static create(value) {

    let node = super.create(value);
    

    node.setAttribute("data-speaker", value.speaker || "Wayne");
    node.setAttribute("data-background", value.background || "Silent");
    node.classList.add("blot");
    return node;
}

        static formats(node) {
          return {
            speaker: node.getAttribute("data-speaker"),
            background: node.getAttribute("data-background"),
          };
        }
      }

      Custom.blotName = "custom";
      Custom.tagName = "span";

      Quill.register(Custom);
```

here I apply the style

```js
document
    .querySelectorAll(".speaker-button")
    .forEach(function (button) {
      button.addEventListener("click", function () {

        // Retrieve existing custom format or create a new object
        var customFormat = quill.getFormat().custom || {};
        
        // Set the speaker, color, and other attributes inside customFormat
        customFormat.speaker = button.getAttribute("data-speaker");
        
        // Handle background attributes inside customFormat
        if (quill.getFormat().custom && quill.getFormat().custom.background) {
          customFormat.background = quill.getFormat().custom.background;
        }
        else {
          customFormat.background = "Silent"; // default background
        }
        // Apply the custom format
        quill.format("custom", customFormat, source = "silent");
        // style the text
        quill.format("color", button.getAttribute("data-color"), source = "silent");
        updateButtonHighlight();
      });
    });
```

I have found out when crashing the event text-changed the problem doesn't occur

```js
quill.on("text-change", function (delta, oldDelta, source) {
  if (source === 'user') {
    w // when i crash it here everthing works and the style is always applied to my custom inline span
  }});
```

But even when I don't have any code running on the text-change event, the error occurs.